Combining Tables in MySQL
I have a Database that hold product records as well as sale location data and I need to have a data set returned with data from different tables
So far I have tried the following code
SELECT 't1' 
productdate, 
productcode, 
productdescription, 
productqty, 
producttotal 
FROM history_product WHERE productdate='2024/07/02'
UNION ALL
SELECT 't2' 
barcodenumber, 
salelocation 
FROM producttable WHERE barcodenumber='t1.productcode';

but I am getting a Error from my SQL Server saying
/ SQL Error (1222): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns /
/ Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0.000 sec. /
All I want is to get the salelocation for a given item from the product record and return it with the data from my history_product
This is a example output from the table



productdate
productcode
productdescription
productqty
producttotal




2024/07/02
1004
NUMATIC HENRY REFURB [W/ KIT]
5
42997


2024/07/02
1012
DYSON V7 CORDLESS
1
14999


2024/07/02
1017
VACUUM CLEANER SERVICE
1
4900


2024/07/02
5030017989345
CARPET SHAMPOO 1.5 LITRES
1
1199


2024/07/02
5053197108184
NUMATIC HENRY SMS BAGS X5
1
699


2024/07/02
746984912341
VAC AIR FRESHER SUMMER MEADOW 6PK
1
199



and I need to use the productcode to get the salelocation from the producttable and add it to the end so it shows like



productdate
productcode
productdescription
productqty
producttotal
location




2024/07/02
1004
NUMATIC HENRY REFURB [W/ KIT]
5
42997
0004


2024/07/02
1012
DYSON V7 CORDLESS
1
14999
0004


2024/07/02
1017
VACUUM CLEANER SERVICE
1
4900
0001


2024/07/02
5030017989345
CARPET SHAMPOO 1.5 LITRES
1
1199
0002


2024/07/02
5053197108184
NUMATIC HENRY SMS BAGS X5
1
699
0005


2024/07/02
746984912341
VAC AIR FRESHER SUMMER MEADOW 6PK
1
199
0002



and then is it possible to sort the result but the salelocation? so when I get it back and shown on screen it would look like this



productdate
productcode
productdescription
productqty
producttotal
location




2024/07/02
1017
VACUUM CLEANER SERVICE
1
4900
0001


2024/07/02
746984912341
VAC AIR FRESHER SUMMER MEADOW 6PK
1
199
0002


2024/07/02
5030017989345
CARPET SHAMPOO 1.5 LITRES
1
1199
0002


2024/07/02
1004
NUMATIC HENRY REFURB [W/ KIT]
5
42997
0004


2024/07/02
1012
DYSON V7 CORDLESS
1
14999
0004


2024/07/02
5053197108184
NUMATIC HENRY SMS BAGS X5
1
699
0005




Sounds like you just need to JOIN the data. It is stating the two tables do not have the same columns. To UNION to columns need to match on both table columns from both the same.

ok so I updated the sql to the following SELECT
history_product.productdate, history_product.productcode,
history_product.productdescription, history_product.productqty,
history_product.producttotal,
producttable.salelocation
FROM history_product
WHERE productdate='2024/07/02'
INNER JOIN producttable ON
producttable.barcodenumber= history_product.productcode; but I still get You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN producttable ON
producttable.barcodenumber= history_product.prod...' at line 8

try it with the inner join AFTER the FROM and use MYSQL date format like this :
SELECT history_product.productdate,
history_product.productcode,
history_product.productdescription,
history_product.productqty,
history_product.producttotal,
producttable.salelocation
FROM history_product
INNER JOIN producttable ON producttable.barcodenumber = history_product.productcode
WHERE productdate = '2024-07-02';

It sounds like you need to read a SQL tutorial. Joins are one of the most basic SQL operations, and you need to learn the syntax.

@easleyfixed Thank you for the example I saw where i went wrong (and I was following a SQL example) but now you have shown me I saw where i went wrong.
